# remove single li using localStorage jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, storage, local

can I get some help on finding a solution on how to remove a single li when using local storage? this is todo list type functionality.

i am able to select & remove "this" item, however, on page/browser refresh the entire ul removes.

what I am trying to do is have only the selected item(s) remove, even if the page/browser does refresh.

i believe the list[i] may be my issue, but what other way could i select $(this) from within localStorage?

```
<h1>simple todo</h1>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add New...">
  <button>Add Item</button>
</form>
  <ul id="list"></ul>

<script>
//add
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var $item = $("input").val();
  $("ul").append("<li>" + $item + "</li>");

//set
$('#form')[0].reset();
  var list = $('#list').html();
  localStorage.setItem('list', list);
  return false;
});

//show
if(localStorage.getItem('list')) {
  $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
}

//remove
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).css("color", "gray");
  var i = $(this).val();
  localStorage.removeItem(list[i]);
  localStorage.clear();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are storing all the `<li>`'s under a single key in the localStorage. And also you call `localStorage.clear()` method which will delete every item in the `localStorage` when you click on a task. That is what causes the issue here.

Comment: @Kjell `//show
if(localStorage.getItem('list')) {
  $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
}` here he is loading the entire list and showing it in the `#list` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your removing method like this

```
//remove
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).css("color", "gray");
    var i = $(this).text();
    var currentList = localStorage.getItem('list');   // get the current list as a string.
    var newList = currentList.replace('<li>' + i + '</li>', '');   // replace the clicked item with a blank string. But if you have multiple tasks with the same name this will cause deleting the first occurrence of it.
    localStorage.setItem('list', newList);  // update the localStorage with the new list
});
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! i still learning JS and jQuery so I appreciate the help. seeing this makes a lot more sense, so thank you!

Comment: glad to help you too! :) I will try to come up with a solution to handle the conflict when there are multiple tasks with the same name. I will update the answer whenever I found one! :)

Comment: you are to kind! thanks a lot for the help sir. very much appreciated.